# what is the meaning of the following syntax in iOS?. typedef void (^something)(NSInteger *a);

Tags: objective-c

New to ios. Let me correct if my understanding is wrong?.

```
typedef void (^someString) (datatype variable_name, datatype variable_name).
```

I am basically from C background.

It is something like a typedef to function pointer ?..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly a function pointer, but a block. A block is an Apple extension to the C language: basically it implements lambda functions. It typedefs the `someString` type to a block returning nothing (`void`) and taking two arguments.

Read more here:
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29)

and here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html

Answer (score 3):

That is the definition of a [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH4-SW1). It's a form of [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) as implemented in Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

its called a block, you can use it like a function but it has a few perks,
check out the [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1)